# Navigation Controller Push View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

**Question**

How to navigate from one view controller to another simply using a button's touch up inside event?

**More Info**

What I tried in a sample project, in steps, was:

1. Create the sample single view application.
2. Add a new file -> Objective-C Class with XIB for user interface (ViewController2).
3. Add a button into ViewController.xib and control click the button to ViewController.h to create the touch up inside event.
4. Go to the newly made IBAction in ViewController.m and change it to this...

   ```
   - (IBAction)GoToNext:(id)sender 
   {
       ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];

       [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
   }
   ```

The code runs without errors and I tested the button's functionality with NSLog. However it still doesn't navigate me to the second view controller. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you actually created a navigation controller and added it to the UI? Is your `[self navigationController]` reference coming back as nil?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Swift3**

```
 **Push**
```

do like

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsDetailsVCID") as NewsDetailsViewController 
 vc.newsObj = newsObj
 navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,
 animated: true)
```

or safer

```
  if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsDetailsVCID") as? NewsDetailsViewController {
        viewController.newsObj = newsObj
        if let navigator = navigationController {
            navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

**present**

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsDetailsVCID") as! NewsDetailsViewController
      vc.newsObj = newsObj
           present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or safer

```
   if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsDetailsVCID") as? NewsDetailsViewController
     {

     vc.newsObj = newsObj
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }





//Appdelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"
                                                       bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}


//ViewController.m

- (IBAction)GoToNext:(id)sender 
{
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];     
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}
```

**swift**

```
//Appdelegate.swift

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let navigat = UINavigationController()
    let vcw = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)

    // Push the vcw  to the navigat
    navigat.pushViewController(vcw, animated: false)

    // Set the window’s root view controller
    self.window!.rootViewController = navigat

    // Present the window
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}

//ViewController.swift

@IBAction func GoToNext(sender : AnyObject)
{
    let ViewController2 = ViewController2(nibName: "ViewController2", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(ViewController2, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I don't recall doing this step before but surely it has worked for me.

Comment: hmm, good, each and every time dont forget that do this in app delegate,k

Comment: i m using appdelegate through push view controller but what for back view controllerin swift 3.0

Answer (score 19):

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyBoardName" bundle:nil];
MemberDetailsViewController* controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerIdentiferInStoryBoard"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Swift 4:

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyBoardName", bundle:nil)
let memberDetailsViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentiferInStoryBoard") as! MemberDetailsViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(memberDetailsViewController, animated:true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code in your button action (Swift 3.0.1):

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(
    withIdentifier: "YourSecondVCIdentifier") as! SecondVC

navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: @EricAya I am very new to this stackOverFlow so just posted something which I saw and applied for myself :)

Comment: @EricAya Okay sir

Answer (score 2):

For **Swift** use the below code:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // Create a nav/vc pair using the custom ViewController class

    let nav = UINavigationController()
    let vc = NextViewController(nibName: "NextViewController", bundle: nil)

    // Push the vc onto the nav
    nav.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)

    // Set the window’s root view controller
    self.window!.rootViewController = nav

    // Present the window
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true

}
```

ViewController:

```
 @IBAction func Next(sender : AnyObject)
{
    let nextViewController = DurationDel(nibName: "DurationDel", bundle: nil)

    self.navigationController.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this code for Navigating next viewcontroller,if you are using storyboard means follow this below code,

```
UIStoryboard *board;

if (!self.storyboard)
{
    board = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
    board = self.storyboard;
}

ViewController *View = [board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourstoryboardname"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:View animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working perfect:

PD: Remember to import the destination VC:

```
#import "DestinationVCName.h"

    - (IBAction)NameOfTheAction:(id)sender 
{
       DestinationVCName *destinationvcname = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DestinationVCName"];
    [self presentViewController:destinationvcname animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Swift:

```
let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("controllerID")
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIViewController *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardId"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's Say **If you want to go from ViewController A --> B** then

1. Make sure your ViewControllerA is **embedded in Navigation Controller**
2. In ViewControllerA's Button click you should have code like this.

@IBAction func goToViewController(_ sender: Any) {

```
    if let viewControllerB = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerB") as? ViewControllerB {

        if let navigator = navigationController {
            navigator.pushViewController(viewControllerB, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

3. Please double check your storyboard name, and ViewControllerB's Identifier mentioned in storyboard for ViewControllerB's View

Look at **StoryboardID = ViewControllerB**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationController is not automatically presented in UIViewController.

This is what you should see in Interface Builder. Files owner has view outlet to Navigation controller and from navigation controller is outlet to actual view;

[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: Maybe I used to create projects that automatically had a navigation controller. If so then what is the way to create a project so that I can find a default navigation controller.

Comment: Open nib of your ViewController and change it as I explained.

Answer (score 0):

```
-  (void) loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
                error:(NSError *)error{
    UINavigationController *nav = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nav"];
    ViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoggedInVC"];
    [nav pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

"nav" is the Storyboard ID for my navigation controller
"vc" is the Storyboard ID for my first view controller connected to my navigation controller

-hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

AppDelegate to ViewController:

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let loginPageView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("leadBidderPagerID") as! LeadBidderPage
var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
rootViewController.pushViewController(loginPageView, animated: true)
```

Between ViewControllers:

```
let loginPageView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("scoutPageID") as! ScoutPage
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginPageView, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 & 5**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourController") as! AlgoYoViewController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,
                                                 animated: true)
```

Answer (score -1):

Create the navigation controller first and provide it as rootViewController of your window object.