# Use pushViewController within app Delegate

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Hi there i want to use this code within the app delegate

```
  ChatController *chatController = [[AppDelegate appDelegate] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GroupController"];
                                            chatController.targetUserid = userid;


                                         [self.navigationController pushViewController:groupChatController animated:YES];
```

how can i push  viewcontroller from appdelegate
i mean make the above code work
cuz self.navigationcontroller doesnt work :$

Comment: if u are using storyboard use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102978/swrevealviewcontroller-without-using-navigationcontroller/23105142#23105142

Comment: if u  are using XIB use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742745/navigation-controller-push-view-controller/20742996#20742996

Comment: Did you verify that self.navigationController == nil? Maybe, the ViewController that call this code is not under a navigationController.

Comment: I mean this code as posted above can it be written within appdelegate cuz i want users to see push notification , if push notification the above code to send user to the chatcontroller
@tyt_g207

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write and define this function in your delegate file,

```
- (void)pushViewControllerFrom:(UIViewController*)controller {
    ChatController *chatController = [[AppDelegate appDelegate] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GroupController"];
                                        chatController.targetUserid = userid;
    [controller.navigationController pushViewController:groupChatController animated:YES];
}
```

Now call the function with your delegate object from the `UIViewController` of you want,

```
[appDelegateObject pushViewControllerFrom:self];
```

Note,
You can create `appDelegateObject` like this,

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

AppDelegate *appDelegateObject = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```