# Objective-C/Xcode - Switch between view controllers programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

How do you switch between view controllers programatically in an effective manner? 
I am currently utilising:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However this does not display the items that I've inserted using the interface builder. Only the items I've inserted programatically.

I wish to do this, as I want to display a home button on each page.

Comment: [self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:viewController animated:YES ];

Comment: are you using StoryBord or XIB?

Comment: use UINavigationController

Comment: you should provide which xib u want to display

Comment: use this link this is hope ful for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742745/navigation-controller-push-view-controller/20742996#20742996

Comment: use initWithNibName. this will work `ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"];`

Answer (score 6):

Give your viewController identity in StoryBord

[image]

then into your code

```
UIViewController *documetController       = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MXDocumentViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:reviewListController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I don't have a navigation controller. Is it required?

Comment: NavigationController is a good way if your dealing with more then one viewController into application. but still you can use [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];