# How can I connect two viewcontroller of two singlepage app in swift by clicking button?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I want open viewcontroller by clicking button on another view controller.all of my project is codebase and i didnt use storyboard.how can i do it?

Comment: Modal Presentation or Push to Navigation stack, depending on your approach. Do it in button's `IBAction` method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation Controller Push View Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742745/navigation-controller-push-view-controller)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
let vc = YourViewController()
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```