# How do I start another view controller with no storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'm not using a storyboard or anything. I'm just creating the cocoa classes and linking them up individually. I can get to load up the default View Controller which is SplashViewController but i can't get past there.

I have experience in php, android programming and python, but i'm totally clueless on how Obj-C and how the iOS framework works :(

SplashViewController.m

```
-(void)initializeInterface
{
    //Initialize start button
    [self.startButton addTarget:self action:@selector(startActivity) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    //Initialize fading backgrounds
    [self animateImages];


}
-(void)startActivity
{

    PhoneViewController *phoneView = [[PhoneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhoneViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:phoneView animated:YES];


}
```

SplashViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PhoneViewController.m"

@class PhoneViewController;

@interface SplashViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) PhoneViewController * phoneViewController;

@property UIImage *splashbg1;
@property UIImage *splashbg2;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *splashbg;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;

-(void)initializeInterface;
-(void)animateImages;
-(void)startActivity;

@end
```

### EDIT

classAppDelegate.m

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //Move from delegate view controller to root view controller
    self.window.rootViewController=[SplashViewController new];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: you should go with storyboard.

Comment: Without view controllers you can not navigate from one to another. for each screen you need individual view controller and class.

Comment: Hmm, I do have an individual view controller and class. PhoneViewController has it's own class and view controller with it's xib as well.

Comment: what is your appdelegate class code

Comment: show your appdelegate didfinish launch method

Comment: why you don't want to use storyboard?

Comment: It's of course totally possible without a storyboard. I suspect your navigation controller is`nil`. Is your splash view controller wrapped in a navigation controller?

Comment: Where/how do you call `startActivity`? What happens? That code looks correct as long as your root view controller is embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. It's unreadable. Edit your question and add the additional code using an `##EDIT` line so we know what's been added.

Comment: @DuncanC apologies, just added it into the question.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik there you go.

Comment: @Paulw11 I just added the calling code for start activity, it is called when the UIButton is pushed.

Comment: As a couple of answers show, you either need to embed your first view controller in a UINavigationController or use `presentViewController`

Comment: see this once bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742745/navigation-controller-push-view-controller/20742996#20742996

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your splash view controller in a navigation controller.

Otherwise, the `navigationController` property of your splash view controller is nil and `pushViewController` has no effect.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: splashViewController];
```

Answer (score 1):

To move from one UIViewController to other UIViewController, you can try the following things

If SecondViewController *secondViewController is the UIViewController you want to move in to, then your can do the following:

```
[self presentViewController: secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This is when you UIViewController is not embedded inside a UINavigationController.

Comment: this works as well. just depends on if we want to use presentViewController instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is **possible** to create your view controllers entirely in code without using Storyboards or XIB files, but it's not recommended. It's like trying to write a complex user application in assembler. The state of the art has evolved since the days when that was necessary. There are better tools. Use them.

Creating everything yourself is both quite complex and not very well documented. You are setting yourself up for a very frustrating, error-prone process. I've been doing iOS development pretty much full time since 2009, and I would not attempt this.

That being said, if you are a masochist, you would create your view controller using `initWithNibName:bundle:`, passing in nil for both parameters, and then implement the `loadView` method. In `loadView` you're create your view hierarchy and install it.

If you are new to iOS/Objective-C, **DO NOT DO THIS**. It is like trying to write a kernel device driver in machine code as your first foray into UNIX.

Answer (score 0):

Change you AppDelegate method as below -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[SplashViewController new]];

    //Move from delegate view controller to root view controller
    self.window.rootViewController=navcon;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Problem in your code, you have not taken any navigationController, that enables you push or pop UIViewController. Doing above you can use your method -(void)startActivity to Start a new ViewController.