# pushViewController does no action

Tags: ios, swift, pushviewcontroller

i have a tableview and i want to go to another vc when one of rows tapped. my didSelectRowAtIndexPath function is as below. print command works and shows the right clicked row. but when i use self.navigationController?.pushViewController it does not go to vc with playVideo storyBoardId. after changing it to presentViewController it works. what's wrong about my code that push doesn't work?

thanks

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("clicked " + String(indexPath.row) )
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("playVideo") as! PlayVideoViewController

    vc.id = self.video[indexPath.row].id

    // Present View as Modal
    //presentViewController(vc as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    // Push View
    //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: PlayVideoViewController is not a root of navigation controller so the pushViewController method will not run. You need to add navigation controller by going to your storyboard, select PlayVideoViewController, at top menu select Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller. Now your PlayVideoViewController will become root of navigation controller and the pushViewController should works fine.

Comment: @muazhud i did it same as you and Bseaborn said. but still it's not working

Comment: Here is my answer for the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/56199240/1371853

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Its because the view controller you are currently in may not have a navigation controller.
- You cannot push a view controller without having a UINavigationController.
- If your requirement is to push a view controller, then perform the following steps.

  1. Embed a navigation controller for the current view controller.(Open storyboard -> Choose your view controller -> Choose "Editor" -> "Embed in" -> UINavigationController)
  2. Now your code

  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

will be working fine.

Comment: i thought it only needs nav controller on destination. big mistake! thanks for your clear answer

Comment: @Bharath, how to do this programatically?

Comment: @Shyam: To illustrate it programatically, lets assume that you are in FirstViewController & want to navigate to SecondViewController in that case first you have to embed the  FirstVC.. in a navigation controller like (let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: FirstVC..)), then you can present this navigation controller. Then inside the FirstVC you can call (self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondVC, animated: true)).

Comment: @Bharath, thanks. Guess, it might not work, because, I'm developing an iMessage only app. And, it is not a proper `UIViewController`, rather a child, with it's one limitations.

Comment: nice i mi case use wfk programatly and this is nil je

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your ViewController is indeed built on a NavigationController. Try forcing the line:

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController
```

if it crashes, you know there is not nav set up. Or you could just check in your storyboard but this is a quick way to tell.

Comment: it crashed. unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. but it has a navigation controller. i don't get it why it says nil

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of your setup. But remove the navigationcontroller from storyboard, tap on the viewController you would like to be embed in the nav. Go to Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why are you doing it like this. I think its unnecessarily complicated.

This should by your function didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("playVideo", sender: tableView)
}
```

Then you can specify as much segues as you want in this function:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "playVideo") {
        let indexPath:NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let PlayVideoViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PlayVideoViewController
        //you can pass parameters like project id
        detailVC.projectID = ids[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Your segue has to be named like this in interface builder:

[image: named segue]

Comment: i'm familiar with segue but in my case, using push is a better option ;)