# How can I push to another screen?

Tags: swift, modal-dialog, push, screen

```
let modalVC = messageViewController.instantiateViewControllerwithIdentifier(self.storyboard!)
self.present(modalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742745/navigation-controller-push-view-controller

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621887-pushviewcontroller?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

**For Pushing your Story board id :**

Do not forget to replace the StoryBoard id and VC name with yours.

```
let objAboutTheSessionVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AboutTheSessionVC") as! AboutTheSessionVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objAboutTheSessionVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: And this question already have lots of answers on SO

Comment: @V_rohit I agree with your thoughts but, if user has asked here i have given answer for his reference. Thanks for taking a point on that.